# Navigation path is red in rviz

Tags: navigation, rviz, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a turtlebot 2 and am working on autonomous navigation.  Whenever I am sending navigation goals in rviz, the path shows up as flashing red instead of green even though the robot is able to execute the navigation.  For navigation of a known path, this is not an issue but when I try to do autonomous gmapping of an unknown environment, the DWA path planning fails often and I think the issue might be related to the red path.  My only thought is that it is related to the robot_footprint because I always get the error "You must specify three points for the robot_footprint."  Anyone know what might be causing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229499/navigation-path-is-red-in-rviz/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your problem has nothing to do with the path color.
You can actually choose this in `rviz`.
See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Path).

You should obviously configure your robot footprint correctly.
However, there is not enough information to help you with the other errors. At least describe the behaviour in more detail (how is DWA failing, what do you expect), what commands do you launch, ...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-18**:
Well, the path is sometimes green but will periodically flash to red, which suggests that this is not a settings problem.  In terms of the robot footprint, I have the robot_radius set to 0.20 in the costmap_common_params.yaml but I get the error "you must set at least three points for footprint.."

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-18**:
I tried setting the footprint to a 0.4x0.4 square and got the error "Footprint spec is empty, maybe missing call to setFootprint?"

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-18**:
There are probably two paths overlapping. There is nothing in rviz that will flash different colors as an indication of an error state.